# What is the roundabout file size of a 1m x 2m pdf?

Tags: print-design, file-size

Just finished exporting a pdf that will be used to print off a 1m x 2m poster. The current file size of the pdf is a rather manic 142.3MB. Is this too big? Shall I compress it further?

Comment: There is no 'ballpark' file size for a pdf based on its printed dimensions. Is that file too big? Only the printer creating the poster can tell you that.

Comment: 142MB is not very large relative to commonly installed system RAM these days BTW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll sometimes have artwork for much smaller dimensions that is over 300MB. If you're going to pass it as a proof there is little harm in compressing it so that it will fit in an e-mail attachment, but do *not* compress the artwork that you send to your printer.

Comment: before you compress it, consider flattening it. If it it too big to email, upload it to your ISP's (probably free w/account) ftp storage and email an href link.

Answer (score 1):

PDF is merely a container. Files size is determined by what is in the container.

Vector data traditionally takes less kb to store. Raster data can easily cause a PDF to increase greatly in file size.

There is absolutely no way for anyone to tell you what a PDF files size should be merely based upon its' dimensions.